# How to draw text in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I would like to draw text at a given point (x, y) in the `Draw` method of a custom `View`.

I have followed [this sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/graphics_and_drawing/core_text/draw_unicode_text_with_coretext/) from the Xamarin site.

This is the View I created:

```
public class MyView : UIView
{
    public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
    {
        using (var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
            DrawText(context, "hello", 20, new CGPoint(0, 0));
            DrawText(context, "how are you", 20, new CGPoint(0, 40));
        }
    }

    private void DrawText(CGContext context, string text, int textHeight, CGPoint point)
    {
        var x = point.X;
        var y = point.Y + textHeight;

        context.TranslateCTM(x, y);

        context.ScaleCTM(1, -1);
        context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);

        var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(text,
            new CTStringAttributes
            {
                ForegroundColorFromContext = true,
                Font = new CTFont("Arial", 16)
            });

        using (var textLine = new CTLine(attributedString))
        {
            textLine.Draw(context);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `DrawText` method **only works OK once**. The first time you call it the text is drawn, but **it doesn't work on successive calls** (it draws nothing, or what it draws isn't visible).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: um - do you need something equivalent to `setNeedsLayout` or the like??  just a wild guess!

Comment: in iOS it, basically, only uses the drawRect routine again, when, `setNeedsLayout` ....

Comment: It should be needed to call SetNeedsLayout. I just want to draw another text within the same context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are two basic things that are wrong with your code.

- You are performing a `ScaleCTM` and a `TranslateCTM` each time you call `DrawText`
- You do not take into account that when you `CTLine.Draw`, the "cursor" is moved to the end of that text.

So, call `ScaleCTM` to flipped the whole thing so the text gets draw left2right, then call `DrawText` and translate to where you want to paint the text and then **translate back** to where you started so the next time you are at the same point.

#### Example Draw override:

```
public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
{
    var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    context.ScaleCTM(1, -1); // you flipped the context, now you must use negative Y values to draw "into" the view

    var textHeight = new CTFont("Arial", 16).CapHeightMetric; // lets use the actaul height of the font captials.

    DrawText(context, "Hello", textHeight, 0, 0);
    DrawText(context, "How are you?", textHeight, 0, 20);
    DrawText(context, "Sincerely,", textHeight, 0, 40);
    DrawText(context, "StackOverflow,", textHeight, 0, 60);
}

void DrawText(CGContext context, string text, nfloat textHeight, nfloat x, nfloat y)
{
    context.TranslateCTM(-x, -(y + textHeight));
    context.SetFillColor(UIColor.Red.CGColor);

    var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(text,
        new CTStringAttributes
        {
            ForegroundColorFromContext = true,
            Font = new CTFont("Arial", 16)
        });

    CGRect sizeOfText;
    using (var textLine = new CTLine(attributedString))
    {
        textLine.Draw(context);
        sizeOfText = textLine.GetBounds(CTLineBoundsOptions.UseOpticalBounds);
    }
    // Reset the origin back to where is was
    context.TranslateCTM(x - sizeOfText.Width, y + sizeOfText.Height); 
}
```

#### Results in:

[image]

#### Using NSMutableParagraphStyle and NSString.DrawString

```
var context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
CGRect textRect = new CGRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 100.0f);
{
    var textContent = "Hello\nHow are you?\nSincerely,\nStackOverflow";
    UIColor.Red.SetFill();
    var textStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle ();
    textStyle.Alignment = UITextAlignment.Left;

    var textFontAttributes = new UIStringAttributes () {Font = UIFont.FromName("ArialMT", 16.0f), ForegroundColor = UIColor.Red, ParagraphStyle = textStyle};
    var textTextHeight = new NSString(textContent).GetBoundingRect(new CGSize(textRect.Width, nfloat.MaxValue), NSStringDrawingOptions.UsesLineFragmentOrigin, textFontAttributes, null).Height;
    context.SaveState();
    context.ClipToRect(textRect);
    new NSString(textContent).DrawString(new CGRect(textRect.GetMinX(), textRect.GetMinY() + (textRect.Height - textTextHeight) / 2.0f, textRect.Width, textTextHeight), UIFont.FromName("ArialMT", 16.0f), UILineBreakMode.WordWrap, UITextAlignment.Left);
    context.RestoreState();
}
```

Comment: Please, check my answer! I have taken your code as base and modified to work with my code. FormattedText is a type that encapsulates the properties of the text to be written and Point is my custom Point structure.

Answer (score 1):

I took @SushiHangover's code and modified it to work for me, since their version (1st in his post) had some problems (read notice below):

```
public void DrawText(FormattedText formattedText, Point point)
{
    context.SaveState();
    context.ScaleCTM(1, -1); 
    context.SetFillColor(formattedText.Brush.Color.ToiOS());

    var sizeOfText = formattedText.DesiredSize;

    var ctFont = new CTFont(formattedText.FontName, formattedText.FontSize);
    var attributedString = new NSAttributedString(formattedText.Text,
        new CTStringAttributes
        {
            ForegroundColor = formattedText.Brush.Color.ToiOS(),
            Font = ctFont
        });

    context.TextPosition = new CGPoint(point.X, -(point.Y + sizeOfText.Height - ctFont.DescentMetric));

    using (var textLine = new CTLine(attributedString))
    {               
        textLine.Draw(context);
    }

    context.RestoreState();
}
```

Keep into account that `FormattedText` and `Point` are custom classes I made to encapsulate the text to be drawn and the point where to draw it. Their properties are as simple as you see :)

**IMPORTANT:** The modifications to @SushiHangover's version are there to

**Avoid side effects** (if I drew a Rectangle after calling the DrawText method, the coordinates were messed up, for instance).
It also had a problem with the x coordinate:

```
context.TranslateCTM(-x, -(y + textHeight))
```

should be

```
context.TranslateCTM(x, -(y + textHeight))
```